# Salvaging a poor bathroom floor

Tags: bathroom, shower, floor

Recently I completed a bathroom remodel mostly on my own. It was an overly-ambitious project and one of the key mistakes I made was rushing the prep-work for the sloped tiled floor.

The bathroom design is "open", with the shower simply part of the room with no wall or glass or anything. I used a continuous linear drain across the middle of the bathroom. the slope was incorrect so that water pools up on one end of the linear drain instead of running to the center. At the time of install, I was unhappy with my job but didn't have much option aside from finishing the project and evaluating whether it would be a real issue.

After using this bathroom for several months now, it's turned into quite an issue that the floor is sloped incorrectly. The pooling water tends to turn foul and soap scum stain are all over the grout and tile, because it doesn't flow properly.

I'd like to avoid completely tearing out the bathroom and redoing it, so my alternative option that I'm looking to get feedback on is:

1. Pour self-leveling cement to create a new flat floor across the entire bathroom, except the shower area.
2. Pour cement curbs around the shower.
3. Install a glass enclosure on top of the curbs.
4. Drill a new hole in the center of the curbed shower area and install a round drain
5. Apply new cement in the shower with correct sloping towards the new round drain.

I'd like to get feeback or tips on ways this process could be improved or changed.

Comment: I think you probably already know what you should be doing. Best is not to kludge in a crappy fix. If that means that you should rip out the whole floor then so be it.

Comment: You can probably epoxy-grout over it to the required slope 1% or 2% slope then apply some finish (tile, epoxy, etc.) But this will raise your floor in some areas. See [this](http://www.epfloors.com/industries-served/food-processing-floors/sloping-to-drains/) for more options.